# Bound of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$a_n=\frac{n\cos(n)+\sin(n^2+2n-5)}{n^2}$$

I am trying to find the bound of this sequence.But I get stuck after some computations. I take $\sin f(x)\leq|f(x)| $ and $|\cos(x)|\leq1$ but I am not sure what to do at the end.Wasted 10 papers.

Comment: what about using $|cos(n)|\leq 1$ and $|\sin(\cdot)|\leq 1$? By "the bound of this sequence," do you mean the limit?

Comment: then i get $\frac{n+1}{n^2}$ all examples I have seen are basic.

Comment: I am confused:  Do you not like $(n+1)/n^2$ for some reason?  It is not really clear what you are looking for.

Comment: I dont know how to find the bound from that

Comment: Wow.  Are you intentionally trying to be unclear?  What do you mean by "the bound" ??

Comment: I have to prove that sequence is bounded below and above. But dont know how to do it.

Comment: So, you don't like $(n+1)/n^2$ because it is not a real number?  Then you should find a real number that is greater than that, for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$.

Comment: Yes I thought that it should be a real number. However I found 2 as $(n+1)/n^2$ seems decreasing.

Comment: I posted a new MSE question about the convergence of this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919326/convergence-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-with-a-n-le-fracn1n2

Answer (score 3):

When $n$ gets large so does $n^2+2n-5$. Since we don't have much control over $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ when $x$ is large we have to face the possibility that $\cos n$ and $\sin(n^2+2n-5)$ both are near $\pm1$ at the same time for certain large $n$. It follows that the best "universal" estimate is
$$|a_n|\leq{n+1\over n^2}\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$

Comment: Very nice results!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plot of Christian Blatter's bounds $\pm (n+1)/n^2$ and $a_n$:
[image]

I posted a new MSE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919326/convergence-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-with-a-n-le-fracn1n2) about the convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$.

Comment: so it is correct to say that $|a_n|<1$ (boundary)

Answer (score 1):

Alex's suggestion that the sequence is bounded by zero is incorrect.  The graph disproves this.

Kelenner's suggestion is at best confusing.  He needs absolute values in multiple places.  His recursive case has not been proven.
m seems to serve two different purposes-
i.  a_n≥ m  but later 
ii. a_m> 0

Feel free to edit with LaTeX, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Compute first $a_1$. I have found $a_1=-0,3689...$. Now use $|a_n|\leq \frac{n+1}{n^2}\leq \frac{2}{n}$. We have $\frac{2}{n}<0,3689...$ for $n\geq 6$. Hence, for $n\geq 6$, we have $a_n>a_1$. Now you see that if $m$ is the minimum of $a_k$, $k=1,2,3,4,5$, we have $a_n\geq m$ for all $n$, and there exists $k\leq 5$ such that $a_k=m$. Hence $m$ is the lower bound you want.

For the upper bound, compute $a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,...$ and find a $m$ such that $a_m>0$, and use the same way of proof.