# convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ with $|a_n| \le \frac{n+1}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us consider series:

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$$

$$a_n=\frac{n\cos(n)+\sin(n^2+2n-5)}{n^2}$$

The bounds for $a_n$ is shown [in this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919025/bound-of-sequence/919118#919118) to be:

$$|a_n| \le \frac{n+1}{n^2}$$

Is it possible to prove that this series is convergent?

Numerical results showed that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{10^5} a_n=-0.931506$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{10^6} a_n=-0.931501$$

Here is a plot of Christian Blatter's bounds $\pm (n+1)/n^2$ and $a_n$:
[image]

From the plot the series, we can see that the terms are oscillating, but not like $(-1)^n |a_n| $. There seems to be some randomness in the number of terms to be positive and number of terms to be negative.

Comment: So it is an alternating series? This should be specified. Otherwise it would diverge

Comment: alternating property is what needs to be proved.

Comment: "rom the plot the series, we can see that the terms are alternating" Actually they are not. Recall that "alternating" means that the signs are $+-+-+\ldots$.

Comment: @Did. Thanks. I changed "alternating" to "oscillating".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $$|\frac{\sin(n^2+2n-5)}{n^2}|\leq\frac{1}{n^2}$$
- $\sum\frac{\cos n}{n}$ is convergent by using dirichlet test.

Comment: gaoxinge nice answer!

Comment: Maybe I'm thick, but is it easy to see that the sum $\sum^N_{k=0}\cos(k)$ is bounded uniformly in $N$? I assume by 'Dirichlet test' you're reffering to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)

Comment: @Teri This definitely can be done but the real question is whether the OP (mike) can do it.

Comment: @Did. You are right.  I can not do it. I took some math classes in physics dept when I was a freshman long time ago and can not remember if we were taught about "Dirichlet test" for convergence. ;)

Comment: Ahha! I was indeed thick; write $\cos (k) =1/2 \ (e^{ik}+e^{-ik})$ and use the formula for the partial sums of the geometric series. If mike is aqcuainted with these, he (at least now) can do it.

Comment: Mathematica showed that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1/n)\cos n=-(1/2)\log(2(1-\cos 1))$

Comment: "I can not do it." But you *accepted* the answer? I will never get it.